# Ignore Invalid SSL-Certificate Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, windows-10, win-universal-app

I've got the following Problem: 
I'm developing a Windows 10 Universal App (UAP) in C# and I'm doing network communication via `WebRequest`... The Problem is that I want to ignore if the Target Server has an invalid SSL-Certificate. How can I do this? Before Windows 10 I would set the Property in `ServicePointManager`, but it is not available in Windows 10... What to do?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Nope, I'm using http now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this is not too late for you.  Was in a similar situation as you.  Here is what I did.

```
var filter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.ChainValidationResult.Expired);
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.ChainValidationResult.Untrusted);
filter.IgnorableServerCertificateErrors.Add(Windows.Security.Cryptography.Certificates.ChainValidationResult.InvalidName);

using (var client = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient(filter))
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri("https://yourwebsite.com");
    }
```

Comment: That's the way I finally did!